# Cannot import django.core

Tags: django

I am trying to setup django with fastcgi on apache. Django is installed and seems to be running correctly but I am having problems with setting up fastcgi.

I decided to test out my dispatch.fcgi script in the interactive python shell line by line and the following line:

```
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
```

results in the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named core.servers.fastcgi
```

I can import django with no problem but import django.core gives yet another ImportError (No module named core).

How can I go about ensuring that I can import django.core. If I can import django then in must be on my path, and so why can I not import core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a file/folder called django somewhere in your path, that isn't the actual path.

try this

```
import sys
sys.path
```

And then check everything in that output to see if there is a file/folder called django(.py) somewhere.

If so, change the path (`sys.path = ['/path/to/directory/below/django/install'] + sys.path`) or move/rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `django.py` module in your working directory or in any other that is in python path.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem and coming across this question like I did, it turns out that fastcgi support has been removed as of Django 1.9, thus you will get this import error if trying to import it. Refer [Using Django with virtualenv, get error ImportError: No module named 'django.core.servers.fastcgi'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471471/using-django-with-virtualenv-get-error-importerror-no-module-named-django-cor)